# Google AMP search form redirect to non-AMP page

Tags: amp-html

With Google AMP pages I want to allow users to enter a search query, which the triggers a redirect to a *non*-AMP page.
So from `www.example.com/articles/mynewsarticle/amp` I want to redirect to `www.example.com/search?q=<userquery>`

I'm looking at the [`amp-form` component](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form), but I can't find how to trigger a redirect to a non-amp page with a dynamic search query.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, if I have understood it correctly. You need to use method get in your form and put the path to your redirect page into the action parameter. Inside your form put an input field with a name "q" and it will be a field for a user request.

```
<form method="get" action="www.example.com/search">
    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you need amp-form component and add redirect header directly to your script.

```
header("access-control-allow-credentials:true");
header("access-control-allow-headers:Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token");
header("access-control-allow-methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("access-control-allow-origin:".$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
header("access-control-expose-headers:AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin");
header("amp-access-control-allow-source-origin:https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Location: your_redirect_url");
```